# How to get Bootstrap Multiselect to reference a controls inside of a asp.net repearter?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, twitter-bootstrap, listbox

I've been using Bootstrap Multiselect on my asp.net project.

Each listbox you want to use the plugin with requires something like this:

```
        <!-- Initialize the plugin: -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#<%= MyListBox.ClientID%>').multiselect();
            });
        </script>
```

I've run into a situation in which the I have listboxes inside a repeater.  How do I initialize the plugin, obtaining the right client id, for each listbox in each repeater section?

Comment: instead of client id, keep a class and initialize based on that class name

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Class instead of the ID. So for each listbox you want to be multiselect, add `class="cbMulti"` (for instance), and in your jquery select, use `'.cbMulti'` instead of `'#<%= MyListBox.ClientID%>'`.